# Ruby replace only part of the Matching String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I replace only part of the String in a Ruby code?

Supposed I have a text file that contains multiple occurrences of the keyword "JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT"

```
JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

and I only want to replace the first occurrence, I can use the #sub instead of gsub

```
a.sub('JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"', 'JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"')
```

however not all files contains

```
JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

some could be

```
JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

I am not sure how to do this in a ruby code?  I can search for the keyword "JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT" only but how do I delete the existing value assignment and replace it with JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m

Newbie Ruby developer.

Comment: `sub(/JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms\d+m -Xmx\d+m"/, ...)`

Comment: Sorry, can you give me a code snippet that I could try?  I am not yet familiar with the ruby coding though.  Thanks

Comment: I thought I gave it: `a.sub(/JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms\d+m -Xmx\d+m"/, 'JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Ohh I get it now...need to brush up on Ruby Regex...can you put your answer below instead of just a comment mate so that I could at least choose it as the correct answer.  Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub) accepts a regular expression as a first param:

```
replacement = 'JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"'
a.sub(/JVM_MEM_ARGS_64BIT="-Xms\d+m -Xmx\d+m"/, replacement)
```